# Email external file using Oracle Forms 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, email-attachments, oracleforms

I have my email settings configured and I am able to send emails via Oracle Forms 11g. Now I have the requirement of attaching PDF saved somewhere in my computer in the email sent. I went through the different procedures but I was not able to send the PDF file successfully.

Thank you.

EDIT: ADDING CODE OF MAIL SENDING PROCEDURE

```
create or replace procedure send4 (p_sender IN VARCHAR2, p_recipient IN VARCHAR2, p_subject IN VARCHAR2, p_message IN VARCHAR2)
IS
crlf         VARCHAR2(2)  := chr(13)||chr(10);
l_mailhost VARCHAR2(255) := <IP ADDRESS>;
v_connection             UTL_SMTP.connection;

BEGIN
V_CONNECTION := utl_smtp.open_connection(l_mailhost, 25);
utl_smtp.Helo(V_CONNECTION, l_mailhost);
utl_smtp.Mail(V_CONNECTION, p_sender);
utl_smtp.Rcpt(V_CONNECTION, p_recipient);
utl_smtp.Data(V_CONNECTION,
'Date: '   || to_char(sysdate, 'Dy, DD Mon YYYY hh24:mi:ss') || crlf ||
'From: '   || p_sender || crlf ||
'Subject: '|| p_subject || crlf ||
'To: '     || p_recipient || crlf ||
'MIME-Version: 1.0'|| crlf ||   -- Use MIME mail standard
'Content-Type: multipart/mixed;'|| crlf ||
' boundary="-----SECBOUND"'|| crlf ||
crlf ||
'-------SECBOUND'|| crlf ||
'Content-Type: text/plain;'|| crlf ||
'Content-Transfer_Encoding: 7bit'|| crlf ||
crlf ||
p_message|| crlf ||
crlf ||
'-------SECBOUND'|| crlf ||
'Content-Type: text/plain;'|| crlf ||
' name="file.txt"'|| crlf ||
'Content-Transfer_Encoding: 8bit'|| crlf ||
'Content-Disposition: attachment;'|| crlf ||
' filename="attachment.txt"'|| crlf ||
crlf ||
p_message|| crlf || -- Content of attachment
crlf ||
'-------SECBOUND--'         -- End MIME mail
);
UTL_SMTP.quit(v_connection);
EXCEPTION
WHEN utl_smtp.Transient_Error OR utl_smtp.Permanent_Error then
raise_application_error(-20000, 'Unable to send mail', TRUE);
END;
```

Comment: Which computer? The middle-tier server where Forms operates? Or the user's computer, the local client?

Comment: well the scenario is that when the report is generated in PDF format and then saved (it also should get emailed) so I am guessing it needs to be done on server end, right? The report contains graph and everything though.

Comment: You should give more info on what you use to send a mail?

Comment: I have edited the post with the procedure called to send emails. Again remember, I don't want text converted into pdf and then sent as attachment, instead a report which is generated needs to be emailed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle Reports 11g to create the PDF you should look into the DISTRIBUTION settings. You can display a PDF as well as email from the same report. Otherwise, consider launching a batch file from your Oracle Form that calls the report and emails from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

UTL_SMTP can't afford the large attachments , here is work around you can attached files 
Create java Source

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "SendMail" AS
  import java.util.*;
  import java.io.*;
  import javax.mail.*;
  import javax.mail.internet.*;
  import javax.activation.*;
  public class SendMail {
     // Sender, Recipient, CCRecipient, and BccRecipient are
     // commaseparated lists of addresses.
     // Body can span multiple CR/LF-separated lines.
     // Attachments is a ///-separated list of file names.
     public static int Send(String SMTPServer,
                            String Sender,
                            String Recipient,
                            String CcRecipient,
                            String BccRecipient,
                            String Subject,
                            String Body,
                            String ErrorMessage[],
                            String Attachments) {
        // Error status
        int ErrorStatus = 0;

        // Create some properties and get the default Session
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.akadia.com", SMTPServer);
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        try {
           // Create a message
           MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

           // extracts the senders and adds them to the message
           // Sender is a comma-separated list of e-mail addresses as per RFC822
           {
              InternetAddress[] TheAddresses = InternetAddress.parse(Sender);
              msg.addFrom(TheAddresses);
           }

           // Extract the recipients and assign them to the message.
           // Recipient is a comma-separated list of e-mail addresses as per RFC822.
           {
              InternetAddress[] TheAddresses = InternetAddress.parse(Recipient);
              msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,TheAddresses);
           }

           // Extract the Cc-recipients and assign them to the message.
           // CcRecipient is a comma-separated list of e-mail addresses as per RFC822.
           if (null != CcRecipient) {
              InternetAddress[] TheAddresses = InternetAddress.parse(CcRecipient);
              msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC,TheAddresses);
           }

           // Extract the Bcc-recipients and assign them to the message.
           // BccRecipient is a comma-separated list of e-mail addresses as per RFC822.
           if (null != BccRecipient) {
              InternetAddress[] TheAddresses = InternetAddress.parse(BccRecipient);
              msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC,TheAddresses);
           }

           // Subject field
           msg.setSubject(Subject);

           // Create the Multipart to be added the parts to
           Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();

           // Create and fill the first message part
           {
              MimeBodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart();
              mbp.setText(Body);

              // Attach the part to the multipart
              mp.addBodyPart(mbp);
           }

           // Attach the files to the message
           if (null != Attachments) {
              int StartIndex = 0, PosIndex = 0;
              while (-1 != (PosIndex = Attachments.indexOf("///",StartIndex))) {
                 // Create and fill other message parts;
                 MimeBodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart();
                 FileDataSource fds =
                 new FileDataSource(Attachments.substring(StartIndex,PosIndex));
                 mbp.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
                 mbp.setFileName(fds.getName());
                 mp.addBodyPart(mbp);
                 PosIndex += 3;
                 StartIndex = PosIndex;
              }
              // Last, or only, attachment file
              if (StartIndex < Attachments.length()) {
                 MimeBodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart();
                 FileDataSource fds = new FileDataSource(Attachments.substring(StartIndex));
                 mbp.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
                 mbp.setFileName(fds.getName());
                 mp.addBodyPart(mbp);
              }
           }

           // Add the Multipart to the message
           msg.setContent(mp);

           // set the Date: header
           msg.setSentDate(new Date());

           // Send the message
           Transport.send(msg);
        } catch (MessagingException MsgException) {
           ErrorMessage[0] = MsgException.toString();
           Exception TheException = null;
           if ((TheException = MsgException.getNextException()) != null)
             ErrorMessage[0] = ErrorMessage[0] + "\n" + TheException.toString();
             ErrorStatus = 1;
        }
        return ErrorStatus;
     } // End Send Class
  } // End of public class SendMail
/
```

Create package body to use above java compiled

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE SendMailJPkg AS
   -- EOL is used to separate text line in the message body
   EOL CONSTANT STRING(2) := CHR(13) || CHR(10);

   TYPE ATTACHMENTS_LIST IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);

   -- High-level interface with collections
   FUNCTION SendMail(SMTPServerName IN STRING,
                     Sender IN STRING,
                     Recipient IN STRING,
                     CcRecipient IN STRING DEFAULT '',
                     BccRecipient IN STRING DEFAULT '',
                     Subject IN STRING DEFAULT '',
                     Body IN STRING DEFAULT '',
                     ErrorMessage OUT STRING,
                     Attachments IN ATTACHMENTS_LIST DEFAULT NULL) RETURN NUMBER;
END SendMailJPkg;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY SendMailJPkg AS
   PROCEDURE ParseAttachment(Attachments IN ATTACHMENTS_LIST,
                             AttachmentList OUT VARCHAR2) IS
   AttachmentSeparator CONSTANT VARCHAR2(12) := '///';
   BEGIN
      -- Boolean short-circuit is used here
      IF Attachments IS NOT NULL AND Attachments.COUNT > 0 THEN
         AttachmentList := Attachments(Attachments.FIRST);
         -- Scan the collection, skip first element since it has been
         -- already processed;
         -- accommodate for sparse collections;
         FOR I IN Attachments.NEXT(Attachments.FIRST) .. Attachments.LAST LOOP
            AttachmentList := AttachmentList || AttachmentSeparator || Attachments(I);
         END LOOP;
      ELSE
         AttachmentList := '';
      END IF;
   END ParseAttachment;

   -- Forward declaration
   FUNCTION JSendMail(SMTPServerName IN STRING,
                      Sender IN STRING,
                      Recipient IN STRING,
                      CcRecipient IN STRING,
                      BccRecipient IN STRING,
                      Subject IN STRING,
                      Body IN STRING,
                      ErrorMessage OUT STRING,
                      Attachments IN STRING) RETURN NUMBER;

   -- High-level interface with collections
   FUNCTION SendMail(SMTPServerName IN STRING,
                     Sender IN STRING,
                     Recipient IN STRING,
                     CcRecipient IN STRING,
                     BccRecipient IN STRING,
                     Subject IN STRING,
                     Body IN STRING,
                     ErrorMessage OUT STRING,
                     Attachments IN ATTACHMENTS_LIST) RETURN NUMBER IS
      AttachmentList VARCHAR2(4000) := '';
      AttachmentTypeList VARCHAR2(2000) := '';
   BEGIN
      ParseAttachment(Attachments,AttachmentList);
      RETURN JSendMail(SMTPServerName,
                       Sender,
                       Recipient,
                       CcRecipient,
                       BccRecipient,
                       Subject,
                       Body,
                       ErrorMessage,
                       AttachmentList);
   END SendMail;

   -- JSendMail's body is the java function SendMail.Send()
   -- thus, no PL/SQL implementation is needed
   FUNCTION JSendMail(SMTPServerName IN STRING,
                      Sender IN STRING,
                      Recipient IN STRING,
                      CcRecipient IN STRING,
                      BccRecipient IN STRING,
                      Subject IN STRING,
                      Body IN STRING,
                      ErrorMessage OUT STRING,
                      Attachments IN STRING) RETURN NUMBER IS
   LANGUAGE JAVA
   NAME 'SendMail.Send(java.lang.String,
                       java.lang.String,
                       java.lang.String,
                       java.lang.String,
                       java.lang.String,
                       java.lang.String,
                       java.lang.String,
                       java.lang.String[],
                       java.lang.String) return int';
END SendMailJPkg;
/
```

Test using below code

```
var ErrorMessage VARCHAR2(4000);
var ErrorStatus NUMBER;

-- enable SQL*PLUS output;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
-- redirect java output into SQL*PLUS buffer;
exec dbms_java.set_output(5000);
BEGIN
   :ErrorStatus := SendMailJPkg.SendMail(
                SMTPServerName => 'localhost',
                Sender    => 'martin.zahn@akadia.com',
                Recipient => 'martin.zahn@akadia.com',
                CcRecipient => '',
                BccRecipient => '',
                Subject   => 'This is the subject line: Test JavaMail',
                Body => 'This is the body: Hello, this is a test' ||
                         SendMailJPkg.EOL || 'that spans 2 lines',
                ErrorMessage => :ErrorMessage,
                Attachments  => SendMailJPkg.ATTACHMENTS_LIST(
                                   'C:\Users\Zahn\Work\sendmail.sql',
                                   'C:\Users\Zahn\Work\ferien-2002.txt'
                                )
   );
END;
/
print
```

Hope this help !